# select all text in contenteditable div when it focus/click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got contenteditable div as below.

```
<div style=" border:solid 1px #D31444" contenteditable="true">12 some text...</div>
```

What I need is, when I click on the div, all the text will automatically get selected. Can you give me solution please?

Comment: This answer provides the most 'correct' way to do what you want:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6150060/2703399

Comment: Create a function called `SelectAll()`. Add it to the div with `onclick` and `onfocus`, including `tabindex="0"` and some `id` for easy selection.
The function:
`const editableDiv = document.getElementById("that-div");`
`window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(editableDiv);`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="border:solid 1px #D31444"
     contenteditable="true"
     onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">12 some text...</div>
```

**Update:** Note that [`document.execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#commands) is now [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) although it [still works](https://caniuse.com/document-execcommand).

Comment: This would be better done using the `focus` event, because using the click event will highlight everything whenever the user tries to click to position the caret.

Comment: Well, probably, but that depends on what the author of the question wants.

Comment: I just tried this in Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 OS X.  Using jQuery 1.9.1, binding to the `focus` _does not_ work.  Binding to the `click` event did select the text:

`$('.editable').on('click', function () { document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null); });`

Comment: After tinkering a bit more I noticed that the `focus` event does work, but there are subsequent events (positioning the cursor, maybe) that undo the selection.  I tried `stopPropagation()`, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/MgASG/1/show/ might help?

Comment: This doesn't work when the user navigates to the contenteditable div with the 'Tab' key.

Comment: @Rudie thank you! I'll have to look into the performance implications of this, but works perfectly for me!

Comment: @berto is correct. Chrome doesn't handle `selectAll` on `focus` correctly, and I [filed an issue about it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=508081). `click` works, but as Tim pointed out, usability suffers when the user wants to select only part of the text.

Comment: You cannot `focus` a div, unless you set its `tabindex` property.

Comment: The elegance of this answer is unparalleled for this task.

Comment: Here is a short and undeprecated solution: `window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(div);`

Answer (score 58):

This will do it. The timer is there for Chrome and Safari because in those browsers, the native browser behaviour that selects the whole element seems to trigger after the focus event, thereby overriding the effect of the selection code unless postponed until after the focus event:

```
var div = document.getElementById("editable");

div.onfocus = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var sel, range;
        if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
            range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(div);
            sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
            range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(div);
            range.select();
        }
    }, 1);
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a way to do this with preventDefault or stopPropagation too? Using setTimeout seems kind of ugly because you have to break the call stack.

Comment: @Adam: I don't think so. You don't want to prevent the editable element from receiving focus, so `preventDefault()` is out. `stopPropagation()` only stops the event from propagating to the next target, which is not useful for this.

Comment: tim, why aren't you a moderator?

Comment: @think123: Three reasons: I haven't put myself forward, I don't really want to and I don't know whether I'd do it well anyway.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - it doesn't require an inline script.  Can I ask what are the various compatibility reasons for the "getSelection", "createRange" property checks etc..?

Comment: @Jonz: `window.getSelection()` and `document.createRange()`, which are both now standardized, are supported in most browsers but not IE < 9. IE does have its own selection/range API though, accessed here via `document.body.createTextRange()`.

Comment: Thanks! I minified your function with UglifyJS2 also... `Element.prototype.SelectAll=function(d){d=this;var sel,range;window.getSelection&&document.createRange?(range=document.createRange(),range.selectNodeContents(d),sel=window.getSelection(),sel.removeAllRanges(),sel.addRange(range)):document.body.createTextRange&&(range=document.body.createTextRange(),range.moveToElementText(d),range.select())}`

Comment: @TimDown I want to set focus() and for some columns need to select text on focus. Unable to figure out these both on this function could you help on it.

Comment: The above can nowadays be replaced by `window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(div);`

Comment: @JasonVasilev: `selectAllChildren` existed in 2010 but not all browsers at the time followed the spec precisely, so I didn't use it in this answer. I don't know whether all current browsers follow the spec now, tbh.

Comment: @TimDown, just checked [MDN selectAllChildren](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/selectAllChildren#browser_compatibility) and support seems flawless. Could you add an update to your answer? It might help people scan quicker for the most modern solution.

Comment: @JasonVasilev What I meant was that `selectAllChildren` existed in all browsers in 2010 but was not implemented the same in all of them, so it's not as simple as just saying "MDN lists support for all browsers" and leaving it at that. However, I will check and update if necessary when I get a moment.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with `focus` event on a `div` is that it can't fire because it thinks a `div` should not be editable. Editable contents in the DOM are marked with `tabindex` in the background, so in order for your div to receive the `onfocus` event, you need to explicitly declare the `div`'s `tabindex` property.
HTML:

```
<div style=" border:solid 1px #D31444" contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" onfocus="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" >12 some text...</div>
```

That should work with `onfocus`.

Comment: Doing this causes it to select the whole entire document. You can use the same code, but I recommend using a `setTimeout` for `150` ms so it won't select the whole document. Hope this helps you all!

Comment: Rather than working around the workaround (see *'XY Problem'* on [Wikipedia](//w.wiki/MfS) & [Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)), use the `<style>` & `<script>` sections (or `.css` & `.js` pages), like the jsGods intended and it won't be an issue; you shouldn't need `tabindex` either. You could use something like a plain ol' `<div id='myDiv'>&nbsp;</div>` styled like `#myDiv{border:solid 1px #d14;}` or whatever, and js `myDiv.addEventListener('click', function(e){this.contentEditable = true; this.focus(); document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null);});`. (Works on FF anyway)