# How to select all text in contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

Before this is flagged as a duplicate, I want you to realize that no one has actually provided a good answer for this specific question. In [select all text in contenteditable div when it focus/click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805852/select-all-text-in-contenteditable-div-when-it-focus-click), the accepted answer and Tim Down's answer are both not helpful, as they only work when the element is already focused. In my case, I want all the text in the contenteditable div to be selected after the click of a button, even if the div was not focused beforehand.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I used some code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse) to come up with my answer. It's 100% jQuery as you asked for as well. Hope you like it :)

```
jQuery.fn.selectText = function(){
   var doc = document;
   var element = this[0];
   console.log(this, element);
   if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
       var range = document.body.createTextRange();
       range.moveToElementText(element);
       range.select();
   } else if (window.getSelection) {
       var selection = window.getSelection();        
       var range = document.createRange();
       range.selectNodeContents(element);
       selection.removeAllRanges();
       selection.addRange(range);
   }
};

$("button").click(function() {
    $("#editable").selectText();
});​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zAZyy/) link.

Comment: What's the browser compatibility on this?

Comment: Fiddle works in FF 28, but doesn't work in for `contenteditable` input-elements with OS theme (CSS `appearance`). You may wanna add `element.focus();` to the `selectText()` function, or it will select the text without the cursor being in that field.

Comment: Just a suggestion, remove the line "console.log(this, element);", since it's not required to work.

Answer (score 13):

For example in next scenario if user set focus into editable div (with mouse, keyboard or by clicking a button) then content of editable div is selected.

```html
<div id="editable" style=" border:solid 1px #D31444" contenteditable="true" 
    onfocus="document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null);">
  12 some text...
</div>
    
<button onclick="document.getElementById('editable').focus();" >Click me</button>
```

On JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QKUZz/

Comment: @think123, see link in updated answer. Why not `document.execCommand`? Another way (I think) required to use `selection` and `range` objects.

Comment: Would you be able to update it and add that as a functionality? Thanks.

Comment: why does selectAll selects everything in the document? :(

Comment: This doesn't work reliably in Chrome 43. Please see the [issue I filed about it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=508081).

Answer (score 4):

Great function.

I've adapted it to enable full selection of text across any number of editable divs via a class, whether clicked directly, or tabbed to:

```
$.fn.selectText = function(){
    var doc = document;
    var element = this[0];
    //console.log(this, element);
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();        
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
};

$(".editable").on("focus", function () {
    $(this).selectText();
});
$(".editable").on("click", function () {
    $(this).selectText();
});
$('.editable').mouseup(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    // maximize browser compatability
    e.returnValue = false;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    return false; 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="editable" style="border:dotted 1px #ccc;" contenteditable="true">01 text...</div>
<div class="editable" style="border:dotted 1px #ccc;" contenteditable="true">02 text...</div>
<div class="editable" style="border:dotted 1px #ccc;" contenteditable="true">03 text...</div>
```

FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/tw9jwjbv/

Comment: Great function, saved my life. I added `$("#mybutton").click(function () {
    $("#mydiv").selectText();
    document.execCommand("copy");` which copy content of the DIV to clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome does select everything, so I just added RAF to work around it:

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => document.execCommand('selectAll'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0aqptw8m/

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="test" style=" border:solid 1px #D31444" contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">12 some text...</div>
```

Judging by this answer provided in the link, cant you use the code on click within your button.

What im saying is even say in the div `onfocus="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)"`

Then use jQuery to trigger focus `$('#test').focus();`