# Edit and Select Text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text field which can be edited using click and i am doing it in jQuery.

Now i was wondering how can i **select all the text** in box when i click `EDIT button`

**[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/zSwBL/)**

Code for edit

```
 $('.edit').click(function () {
     $(this).siblings('.edit-section').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
     $(this).siblings('.edit-section').attr('style', 'border:2px solid;');
     $(this).attr('style', 'display:none;');
     $(this).siblings('.done').attr('style', 'display:li;');
 });
```

**I cannot add separate click function for .edit-section**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
 $('.edit,.done').click(function () {
     var section = $(this).siblings('.edit-section');
     var isEdit = $(this).is('.edit');
     section.prop('contenteditable',isEdit).css('border',isEdit?"2px solid":"none");
     $('.edit').toggle(!isEdit);
     $('.done').toggle(isEdit);
     if(isEdit){section.focus(); document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null); }
 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zSwBL/9/)

---

[<sub>Source</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243898/how-to-select-all-text-in-contenteditable-div)

Answer (score 3):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/zSwBL/6/)**

```
jQuery.fn.selectText = function () {
    var doc = document;
    var element = this[0];
    console.log(this, element);
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
};

$(".edit").click(function () {
    $(".edit-section").selectText();
});
```

from : [Selecting text in an element (akin to highlighting with your mouse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate - [Programmatically select text in a contenteditable HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139107/programatically-select-text-in-a-contenteditable-html-element)

Copied following function from the answer.

```
function selectElementContents(el) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}

var el = document.getElementById("foo");
selectElementContents(el);
```

Updated JS-Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vishwanatharondekar/zSwBL/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jQuery.fn.selectText = function(){
    var doc = document;
    var element = this[0];
    console.log(this, element);
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();        
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
};

$("button").click(function() {
    $("#editable").selectText();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zSwBL/10/)

Refence: [How to select all text in contenteditable div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243898/how-to-select-all-text-in-contenteditable-div)