# How to make text inside a Div selectable, that is behind an other Div with superior z-index?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Working on a bunch of code, couldn't easily copy the part in here that seems broken because I'm not sure where the problem is at. Situation: there's text inside a div that I need to make selectable, but there's an other div with higher Z-index on top that doesn't allow me to select the text in the lower-z-indexed div. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Add related code here https://jsfiddle.net/ and someone will surely help

Comment: If you don’t need to be able to “interact” with the upper element, then `pointer-events` could help solve this.

Comment: Try this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243898/how-to-select-all-text-in-contenteditable-div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
#b{
    position:fixed;
    background-color: blue;
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index:5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lp0uowg8/)

Comment: Should be noted that `pointer-events` are IE11 and up only. - http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events