# Trigger selection of contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

**Why does this doesn't select (ie highlight in blue etc.) the contenteditable `<div>` ?**

*Note: I'm using Firefox 36.0.1 (Windows 7)*

```js
$('#b').click(function() { $('#a').select().focus(); } );
```

```html
<div id="a" contenteditable>Hello</div>
<div id="b">click here</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems to work for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: @putvande firefox 36.0.1

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243898/how-to-select-all-text-in-contenteditable-div

Comment: @Basj -- Did you try to actually type something?   contenteditable is html5 -- your browser may simply be too old to support it (I have FF 44 and works fine)

Comment: However [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable) suggest that it should work fine with your browser

Comment: @Soren no no, FF 36 supports contenteditable since a long time, I use it in many projects. The problem doesn't come from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12244228/1422096), this works, at least with Firefox:

```js
$('#b').click(function() { $('#a').select().focus(); document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null); } );
```

```html
<div id="a" contenteditable>Hello</div>
<div id="b">click here</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The select() function is not for a contenteditable Element. see@
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select.

The **HTMLInputElement.select()** method selects all the text in a **< textarea >** element or an **< input >** element with a text field.

You can set a Range to select the text or a part of the text.
To select the contenteditable text you can use this:

```
function selectAll() {
  var editor = document.getElementById('a');
  var selection = document.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(editor);
  selection.addRange(range);
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNPGxW