# Onselect for contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to select all content for a div when it gets selected (ie contenteditable div is switched to via "tab" on the keyboard). It might look something like:

```
  document.getElementById("abc").addEventListener("select",function(){
     document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null);
  });
```

Why does this not work and how should I go about doing it? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243898/how-to-select-all-text-in-contenteditable-div

Comment: somehow I couldn't find that. thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select all text in contenteditable div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243898/how-to-select-all-text-in-contenteditable-div)