# js copy function not working in html

Tags: javascript, html, copy

I'm trying to get a copy button on my html page but it won't work - in the chrome console it states nothing, it just won't copy the text.

this is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<div class="ipDiv tk-saffran">
  <div class="ipText">
    <h2 id="ip">play.MineGlade.net</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="copyButton">
    <button onclick="copyIp()">Copy IP</button>
    <script>
      function copyIp() {
        var copyText = document.getElementById("ip");
        copyText.select;
        document.execCommand("Copy");
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: If you use input field instead of h2 tag, then it will work fine. <input id="ip" value="play.MineGlad.net" />

Comment: Do you want to copy "play.MineGlade.net" into your clipboard?

Comment: Try var copyText = document.getElementById('ip').innerHTML;  document.execCommand('Copy);

Comment: Check this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_copy_clipboard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is **easy and simple way** to do copy, Please review this updated code

```js
function copyIp()
{
    window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(document.getElementById("ip"));
    document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

```html
<div class="ipDiv tk-saffran">
    <div class="ipText">
        <h2 id="ip">play.MineGlade.net</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="copyButton">
        <button onclick="copyIp()">Copy IP</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's not an IP

Comment: @Luca it's the server address to my Game Server, in minecraft it's commonly called an IP-address even if it's a domain name with DNS records to point to the actual IP.

Comment: @SanjayKumarSingh I don't know how to "mark" answers, I'm quite new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select h2 content which will not work with select function, also you'r not calling it right it should be .select(). To select content of element please check [this thread](https://jsfiddle.net/ohzstgvd/): [How to select all text in contenteditable div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243898/how-to-select-all-text-in-contenteditable-div)

Please see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohzstgvd/) I made for you with your example

```
    <div class="ipDiv tk-saffran">
        <div class="ipText">
            <h2 id="ip">play.MineGlade.net</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="copyButton">
            <button onclick="copyIp()">Copy IP</button>
            <script>
                jQuery.fn.selectText = function(){
                   var doc = document;
                   var element = this[0];
                   console.log(this, element);
                   if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
                       var range = document.body.createTextRange();
                       range.moveToElementText(element);
                       range.select();
                   } else if (window.getSelection) {
                       var selection = window.getSelection();        
                       var range = document.createRange();
                       range.selectNodeContents(element);
                       selection.removeAllRanges();
                       selection.addRange(range);
                   }
                };
                function copyIp() {
                   $("#ip").selectText();
                   document.execCommand("Copy");
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Make sure your include jquery with this to work.