# select editable text on focus with execCommand

Tags: angular, textselection, execcommand

I've got a simple code that is suppose to select all contents of the element that was focused:

html:

```
  <div tabindex="-1" class="data" contenteditable="true"  (focusin)="focusin($event)" (focusout)="focusout($event)"  >Content</div>
```

.ts:

```
focusin(e) {
  console.log("focusin");
  document.execCommand("selectall");
}
```

The problem is that this code selects all text in the document, not just the one that was focused in. From what I see on the web, this is not how select all should work, if an element is focused:

[How to select all text in contenteditable div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243898/how-to-select-all-text-in-contenteditable-div)

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that works for Chrome and most recent browsers versions :

```
focusin(e) {
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(e.target);
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

Comment: Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tutorial-n9usa3?file=app/app.component.ts