# How to select all text in contentediatable element when focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I want to select all the text in contenteditable element when focusing and not on clicking. Tab should trigger the selection here. I found this approach [select all text in contenteditable div when it focus/click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805852/select-all-text-in-contenteditable-div-when-it-focus-click) but that is on clicking which does not work for tab and does not let the user to select part of the text.
In the link provided I tried `onfocus` instead of `onclick` and surprisingly does not work.

Comment: What have you tried? Typically, you need to show your specific attempts (with code), in order to get a good answer.

Comment: If you look at the answer in the link you provided you will see a comment by user "Rudie".   Rudie solved the onfocus issue by delaying execution of the select using requestAnimationFrame.  You could probably achieve a similar result with `setTimeout` in your `onfocus` handler.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kfypq/2/ It does not work with `setTimeout`

Comment: You are calling document.execCommand.   Look more closely at Rudie's example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kfypq/4/ one thing remained which is when focusing the element using tab, the function should not `preventDefault()` of `mouseup`

Comment: Did you try [my answer to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3806004/96100)?

Comment: @TimDown It works exactly how I want it. Thank you so much.