# make the cursor select whole content of the contenteditable td on click in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

the whole text to be selected on click in jQuery

```
  <tr>
  <td class="wt" type="text" contenteditable="true" align="right">0.00</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select all text in contenteditable div when it focus/click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805852/select-all-text-in-contenteditable-div-when-it-focus-click)

Comment: yes i have tried select

Comment: $(".wt[type=text]").click(function() {
   $(this).select();
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```js
$('#selectAll').on('focus', function() {
  var cell = this;
  var range, selection;
  if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(cell);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(cell);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td><div id="selectAll" contenteditable="true">0.00</div></td>
</tr>
```